# Outlook fail to receive large e-mails from yahoo mail with error 0x800ccc0f or error 0x80042112

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, yahoo-mail

Two months ago Outlook suddenly started having big difficulty receiving any big e-mail (usually bigger than 3-4MB)  threw pop3 from my yahoo webmail.
All regular small sized mail is downloaded without problem. Only big e-mails have difficulty.
I don't face any problems with sending.
The pop3 is configured using port 995 (SSL).

The problem is happening on both my windows 7 computer with outlook 2013 (both errors 0x800ccc0f or error 0x80042112) and on my windows xp computer with outlook 2003 (error 0x800ccc0f) . I have norton internet security on both. Outlook is configured to leave a copy of the message on the server.

Usually the mail download progress reach 100% before either error 0x800ccc0f or error 0x80042112 occur.
Occasionally one of the big e-mails is downloaded successfully but that is rare.

I tried the following until now without success:
1- increased time-out in outlook
2- disabled my antivirus and antispam and then even uninstalled it completely
3- tried to download message headers and processing one e-mail per time but still received error 0x800ccc0f

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Sounds like Yahoo changed its policy on the size of allowed attachments.  Have you verified the attachment can actually be downloaded from a browser?

Comment: Yes, I can download the attachment from the browser easily. And as I mentioned occasionally one of the big e-mails is downloaded to outlook.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I'm putting up an answer to help anybody who stumbles upon this..

I experienced the same and verify that this seems to be a problem with allowed size of attachments and how Outlook treats them. I moved a message with >20MB attachment to a temporary folder outside of 'Inbox' on Yahoo webmail and then Outlook was able to complete the send and receive process. Interestingly, the message with >20MB attachment had been downloaded successfully prior to this. Furthermore, the attachment was also downloaded successfully from Yahoo Webmail.

Comment: Can you clarify what your solution is?

Comment: Could this be due to a storage quota limit ?

Comment: @fixer1234 The solution I came up with was to move the message with huge attachment to a temporary folder outside of 'Inbox' and then run 'Send and Receive' in Outlook.

Comment: @suspectus I don't think so. I have a Yahoo! Small Business account with 1 TB storage.

Comment: That's the confusing part.  Yahoo only downloads messages from its inbox.  Moving a large message to another folder might free up Yahoo to download other messages, but not the moved large one (which is what the question asks).  At least that's been my own experience.